# Installed ubuntu16.04 with apache2, created a website and the site php page not loading, but html is

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, virtualhost

I have created a apache server with digital ocean, on ubuntu 16.04.
I was following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) and [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) .

The index.html files loads but the index.php not. What might be wrong.

Comment: Test phpinfo() - if that doesnt work, then your php/apache setup is not properly configured. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php for more informations about phpinfo

Comment: The apache tutorial you used does not even mention php - so maybe you haven't even installed php which might explain the problem ;)

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Regarding @NickT's link: ignore the MySQL section if you don't need a database.

Comment: 'code' I have installed php as mentioned in the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04, and tested the info.php, worked correctly, Have also added phpmyadmin and configured the database as required by the website, but the problem is still there

Comment: If info.php (following NickTs link) is displayed correct - your php installation is working. Please give us more details then what your  current problem is now ... as the start-problem is solved ;)

Comment: 'code'As I have uploaded the website using virtual host training, and the sample output has output correctly on html, but when I have uploaded the actual website, which is a php version I get a blank page. Even the site/index.php results in blank page

Comment: I added a page without connecting to db and worked correctly, but the site with DB did not work correctly, it shows a blank page

Comment: Time to dig into the logs then to see what errors it throws. Consider checking the apache & mysql logs.

Comment: 'code' I see that the configuration is configured to access mysqli not mysql, how to configure to use mysql

Comment: 'code'php.ini I have disabled everything on mysqli, which enables of mysql do I need to activate

Answer (score 0):

## In short

Install and configure PHP.

## Longer

Please follow the [instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) of your host.

The most relevant bit begins in Step 3 with the installation of the related packages:

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
```

But please read the entire document carefully as it does contain additional important informations (regarding modules, testing etc)

Comment: 'code' I have done the installation as mentioned on this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04 earlier to setting up the website

Comment: And is the problem solved now? Did you run phpinfo?

Comment: 'code' No, the steps I followed is first I have installed and configured apache as mentioned in my last post then I have added the website, but the problem is the question what I asked

Comment: As mentioned above - the link you posted in the base-question is not even covering PHP - therefor php files wont work on the apache server. NickT posted a better matching link which you should follow to setup PHP as well.

Comment: 'code'Have installed the php first then added the website, I have edited the question,